# PHP string function for formatting search result

Tags: php, string, search, formatting

I'm using MySQL fulltext search and need to format search result in described below manner.

Is in PHP or some library function, that gets specified parameters and returns specified result?
If no, has anyone an implementation of similar function?

```
$needles = ['word1', 'word2'];
$haystack = 'This string contains word1. Also this string contains word2';
$wordsGap = 1;  //word quantity from left and right of every in $result;
$delimiter = '...';
$result = desired_function($needles, $haystack, $wordsGap, $delimiter);
//$result must be String like '... contains word1. Also ... contains word2'
```

**UPDATES**
I need result similar to this one.
http://joxi.net/BA01zg3tJ4l5Or

For now I HAVEN'T desired_function. But I need it. I need a function that gets described parameters and returns described result.

Comment: I found Correct answer there:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23330035/1638298

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use the php function  http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Hi. I've updated my question, so task is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you meant by the `wordsGap` and `delimiter` but the below functions will return an array with the found words :

```
function cool_function($needles, $haystack, $wordGap, $delimiter){


    $haystack = explode(' ', $haystack);
    $mFinalArray = [];

    foreach($haystack as $current){

        foreach($needles as $currentNeedle){
            if(strpos($current, $currentNeedle) !== false){
                $mFinalArray[] = $currentNeedle;
            }
        }
    }

    return $mFinalArray;
}
```

Example :

```
$needles = ['word1', 'word2'];
$haystack = 'This string contains word1. Also this string contains word2';
$wordsGap = 1;  //word quantity from left and right of every in $result;
$delimiter = '...';
$result = cool_function($needles, $haystack, $wordsGap, $delimiter);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => word1
    [1] => word2
)
```

You can play at the line

`$mFinalArray[] = $currentNeedle;`

if you want to add the delimiter and wordsGap, but from the time you have your data you can show whatever you like.

Comment: Hi. I've updated my question, so task is more clear now.

Comment: That's not clear enough for me..Maybe update your question with a real example. Real inputs, real expected outputs the way you want them. Plus right now you have a function which returns what you need..