# MySQL SQLite snippet() function equivalent

Tags: mysql, sqlite

There is a great snippet() function in SQLite (FTS4/5 query), which returns number of words surronuding search matches, a part of text containing a query (if matched). You can highlight search term, and, what's most important, you don't get the whole article, but just the part (substring) with matches.
Is there a MySQL equivalent of it?

I'm totally newbie in MySql, but here's what I coded for now:
The column string is 
    'Lorem ipsum dolot sit amet fly, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod fly tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'

The query string is 'fly'.

(I don't know jet, how to pass/operate search query to SQL function, in this case 'fly'?) Yes, I know about SQL injection, it's just a quick example.

```
<?
$db = new PDO(...);
//
$sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
    CREATE TABLE test(tekst TEXT) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_520_ci;
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx ON test(tekst);
INSERT INTO test(tekst) VALUES('Lorem ipsum dolot sit amet fly, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod fly tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.');
";
//
$db->exec($sql);
//
$db->query("SET @off = 16; #char offset
SET @co = 'fly' COLLATE utf8_unicode_520_ci; #the search word
SET @lewa = '' COLLATE utf8_unicode_520_ci; #left string from the match
SET @prawa = '' COLLATE utf8_unicode_520_ci; #right string from the match
");
//
$sql = "SELECT 
@lewa := LEFT(tekst,LOCATE(@co,tekst)-@off),
@prawa := SUBSTRING(tekst,LOCATE(@co,tekst)+@off), 

REPLACE(
    TRIM(TRAILING @prawa 
        FROM 
    TRIM(LEADING @lewa FROM tekst))
    ,@co,CONCAT('<b>',@co,'</b>')
    ) trimmed

FROM test WHERE MATCH(tekst) AGAINST(CONCAT(@co,'*') IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
//
$odp = $db->query($sql)->fetch();
//
echo $odp["trimmed"];
?>
```

Returns: "dolot sit amet **fly**, consectetur"
But it only works for one word in query.

Comment: Some advice/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292121/how-to-generate-the-snippet-like-those-generated-by-google-with-php-and-mysql

Comment: But it's all after. MySQL way?

Comment: "Is there a MySQL equivalent of it?" No MySQL does not support that.

Comment: Yes, I know. But any advice to write a Mysql function for that?

Comment: Not really sure what kind of an answer you are are expecting to this. The answer to the question you asked has already been provided by Raymond. If you would like to implement this feature yourself, then go ahead and do it. Happy to help you if you get stuck.

Comment: The thing is to get just a bit of long text containing matches:
"This is a long article xxx xxxx xx xxxxx fly xxx xx x xxxxxx xxx etc..."
so the query search for 'fly' will return just "... xxxx xx xxxxx fly xxx xx ..." - not the whole article.
Like: "SELECT shorter(article) article FROM book WHERE MATCH(article) AGAINST('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"

Comment: I understand your ultimate goal. What I do not understand is what answer you expect here. Your question is `Is there a MySQL equivalent of it?` The answer is no, there is no such function in mysql. Then you asked `But any advice to write a Mysql function for that?` The answer to this is going to be either sarcastic or would be a full implementation of the code. The latter is unlikely to happen because nobody is going to implement a complex feature ftom scratch for you. You must get started and if you get stuck, then ask a specific question about that.

Comment: The following meta post applies to your second question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question